# The error in matlab:Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.​IllegalArg​umentExcep​tion: Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: matlab, runtime-error

I started receiving an error in matlab, which prevents me to see the command window but does not prevent the code from executing. I attached all the error message below. I do not know why this is happening but I guess it started after I used "save" commands in the editor. I basically load data into the editor and then preprocess the data so that I can use them later, and I save the new data for future computations. Since when I started saving data, this problem has been initiated. Now, I can't stop matlab to produce this error every time I run any code. Can you please help me with this? I really appreciate that, thank you.

Original error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract! at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(Unknown Source) at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source) at   java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(Unknown Source) at   java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source) at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source) at java.util.ArrayList.sort(Unknown Source) at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.widgets.grouptable.GroupingTableUtils.sortNonRecursively(GroupingTableUtils.java:296) at com.mathworks.widgets.grouptable.RowListTransactionTarget.finishTransaction(RowListTransactionTarget.java:115) at com.mathworks.widgets.grouptable.GroupingTableTransaction$1.run(GroupingTableTransaction.java:112) at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) >>

Comment: 1) Which version of MATLAB is this? 2) Did you customize your MATLAB installation in any way (UI, Java version, `startup.m`,...)? 3) Try backing up and clearing your `prefdir` and re-running MATLAB - this might help.

Comment: Hi, 1) It is MATLAB R2014a. 2) I did not change those settings. 3) Do you mean deleting everything in prefdir (I assume that is the folder appearing as the file directory when I execute prefdir command in command window)? Then, that would not prevent matlab to work, right? Thank you very much!

Comment: This is how you reset your MATLAB settings. If this folder doesn't exist it is created at runtime.. But you didn't really have to ask me this :)